# Mock service from module A available to module B via module C

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

#### INTRODUCTION

```
angular.module('myApp.Services', []);
angular.module('myApp.Controllers', []);
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.Controllers', 'myApp.Services'])

angular.module('myApp.Services').service('fooSrvc', function(){});

angular.module('myApp.Controllers')
    .controller('FooCtrl', ['fooSrvc', function(fooSrvc){}]);
```

`myApp` module is the main module of the app and it is dependant on `myApp.Services` and `myApp.Controllers` modules.

`myApp.Controllers` **has no direct dependency on** `myApp.Services` module, yet `fooSrvc` from `myApp.Services` module **is available for injection to** `FooCtrl` from `myApp.Controllers` module.

Ok somehow this just works and i can accept it for granted although i wonder how.

But take this to the level of unit testing the `FooCtrl`. I need to mock `fooSrvc`. Ok i can just mock it:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  module('myApp.Controllers');

  module(function($provide) {
    $provide.service('fooSrvc', function() {
      // Mocking fooSrvc
    });
  });
});
```

#### QUESTION

Should i mock any module and is this module organization bad because of magic dependency between modules `myApp.Controllers` and `myApp.Services`?

Comment: You should **definitely** add `myapp.Services` as a dependency of `myapp.Controllers`. As far as unit tests go, I would always create mocks / stubs / spies of collaborators (eg `fooSrvc`)

Comment: The only reason it *works* is because your main app is bringing in all the required modules. When looked at in isolation, your `myapp.Controllers` module has an unmet dependency.

Comment: You're right, i had to mock `myApp.Services`. Wrap it up in the answer :)